# How to identify non-existent nodes quickly

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 5 labels, and each label has a node_id property. I was given a million node ids in a csv file. Now how can i use cypher to find out the node ids that do not exist in any of the 5 labels?

Comment: To add, the node id property is indexed for all 5 labels.

Comment: is the node_id property value unique across all nodes or only in the context of each label?

Comment: Does the CSV file provide the labels for each `node_id`?

Comment: @Dave, as far as what i have tested and seen,  the node id is unique across all nodes but not 100% sure

Comment: @cybersam, no the CSV only provide node ids without any label information.

Comment: you could try to add a 6th label to all of the nodes in your DB and create a constraint on `node_id` over the 6th label. If it fails to create I guess you will have your answer. If it succeeds then I would use that for your searches.

Comment: @DaveBennett we also need to generate a list of node ids from the csv that do not exist in the 5 labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking @DaveBennett's suggestion, you could follow these steps:

1. Create an index for a new label (say, `Foo`):

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON :Foo(node_id);
   ```
2. Create a new `Foo` node for all the used `node_id`s. If only nodes with one of the 5 labels have a `node_id` property, then you can do this:

   ```
   MATCH (n)
   WHERE EXISTS(n.node_id)
   CREATE (:Foo {node_id: n.node_id});
   ```

   Otherwise, you can do this (for labels `L1` through `L5`):

   ```
   MATCH (n)
   WHERE (n:L1 OR n:L2 OR n:L3 OR n:L4 OR n:L5) AND EXISTS(n.node_id) 
   CREATE (:Foo {node_id: n.node_id});
   ```
3. Use the `:Foo(node-id)` index to find all the unused `node-Id` values:

   ```
   LOAD CSV FROM '...' AS line
   OPTIONAL MATCH (f:Foo {node_id: line[0]})
   WHERE f IS NULL
   RETURN line[0] AS unused;
   ```
4. Optionally, delete the `Foo` nodes. (You can also drop the `:Foo(node-id)` index, which is not shown).

   ```
   MATCH (n:Foo)
   DELETE n;
   ```